# how to resolve .local mDNS on android (Unable to resolve host error)

Tags: android, networking

Our android app has the necessary permissions for the internet. Normally it's working well. Recently we need to change the url (not the IP address, but "xxx.xxx.xxx.local") to let the app to run within one LAN environment, the wifi icon is with the exclamation sign (no internet) in the android phone. When try to login the app, mobile app shows this "Unable to resolve host" error, but the android phone can open the url in the browser.

I had gone through other 2 same questions, didn't find the same scenario. It seems browser can solve the host from the wifi router maybe, but the app cannot. Do we need to change any settings to let app to work on LAN environment?

P.S. the url is xxx.xxx.xxx.local

After doing some search, it seems android don't support mDNS (xxx.local) domain totally?  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140786115?pli=1
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36932514

Chrome on Android can access is due to chrome has bypassed android domain resolving.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405925